# How much internet uptime is required for running parachain or parathread?

Tags: parachain, validator

I have a home internet connection of 80-95% uptime with 7-10 Mbps speed. Is it possible to run a parachain or parathread node without taking any cloud services?

Here, is some docs: The good news is that 100% uptime of your validator is not really needed, as it has some buffer within eras in order to go offline for a little while and upgrade. Remember, even if your validator goes offline for some time, the offline slash is much more forgiving than the equivocation or parachain validity slashing.

https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-guides-secure-validator

But I couldn't find documentation for running a parachain or parathread. To complicate matters, each parachain and parathread would have its own incentive system and different criteria for running the node.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can run it on your local machine if it is for testing purposes. To run a production environment node on local system is not advisable but you can runt it without taking any cloud services.